# Conditionally change the types of certain properties when serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a custom class, which I am serializing using JSON.NET.
In that class, lets call it `posInvoice`, I have properties such as `UnitPrice`, `Quantity`, and `TotalAmount` which are of type string. This works fine when I send the serialized object to an endpoint as a POST Request.

Now I have another endpoint, which accepts the same class, `posInvoice`. However, this endpoint is expecting these values to be decimals instead.

What would be the best way to handle this in my code? Should I just create another class and change the property types? I have researched and tried to look for a similar situation in Stack Overflow, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can not pass the same json to the other end point ?

Comment: exact same json, just some types will be decimal, not string

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach I would take:

1. Define your `PosInvoice` class using decimals, since that is the most appropriate data type for the amounts.
2. Create a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) class which can be used during serialization to convert the decimals to strings.
3. Use the converter with the endpoint which requires the amounts as strings; omit it otherwise.

Model class:

```
public class PosInvoice
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class InvoiceAmountsAsStringsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(PosInvoice);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        PosInvoice invoice = (PosInvoice)value;
        JsonObjectContract contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(PosInvoice));
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (JsonProperty prop in contract.Properties)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(prop.PropertyName);
            object propValue = prop.ValueProvider.GetValue(invoice);
            if (propValue is decimal)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(((decimal)propValue).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }
            else
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, propValue);
            }
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static string SerializeInvoice(PosInvoice invoice, bool serializeDecimalsAsStrings)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
    if (serializeDecimalsAsStrings)
    {
        settings.Converters.Add(new InvoiceAmountsAsStringsConverter());
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invoice, settings);
}
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4beAW3